# How can I test if redis service is running using serverspec service resource?

Tags: rspec, redis, test-kitchen

I am using [Test-Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/wiki/Getting-Started) with the [serverspec](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html) busser. I am trying to test the [redis](http://redis.io/) service is running into my kitchen instance.

It is my serverspec test.

```ruby
describe "myapp::redis" do    
  describe service ('redis6379') do
    it { should be_enabled }
    it { should be_running }
  end    
end
```

But when I run the command `kitchen verify` it is the result

```ruby
myapp::redis      
  Service "redis6379"       
    should be enabled       
    should be running (FAILED - 1)
```

It test tell me that the redis service is enable but it is not running.

And what happened here?

How can I use the serverspec service resource to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug in ServerSpec. These types of questions are better asked as issues on the project on GitHub. The developer will be able to give you a better response and you might have uncovered a bug.